# What was the relationship between science and religion in the European early middle ages?

Tags: middle-ages

What was the relationship between science and religion in the early middle ages of Europe?

[Faith and Reason proposal on Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/118246/faith-and-reason-science-and-religion?referrer=nJX-fB6PnlSvJF7EBQIt_Q2)

Comment: Was there science?

Comment: @Spencer: "Was there science?" -- Precisely! 

Science did not exist as a discipline during the early middle ages. There were people doing science -- Jean Buridan, a French priest and teacher at the University of Paris in the 1300s came surprisingly close to scooping Galileo -- but mathematics (other than geometry) was not yet developed enough.  It took centuries of slow development for people to realize that natural science was worth studying and for it to become an independent discipline.  

In the middle ages, what science was done, was usually part of philosophy.

Comment: There was no science in Europe in the early middle age. Ancient science was already forgotten, and new one still had to be born.

Comment: @Alex It's much more subtle than that!  The ancients did not distinguish science from philosophy from mathematics (and in some cases, e.g., the Pathagoreans, from religion).  The neat divisions of knowledge we have today simply didn't exist.  Aristotle wrote on science and on pure philosophy and on morals and on literature or oratory. Herodotus wrote the first history, but a big chunk of it was what we'd call "natural history" -- in his day (and in Pliny the Elder's) it was all one.  Because the question is framed in modern terms, it to some extent begs its answer.

Comment: @Mark Olson: I disagree.  The ancients may have done a good deal of natural history, but they didn't do science.  The difference is in how you approach a subject.  Simplistically (there are whole books written on the subject) the ancients used a philosophical approach: decide what something ought to be on ethical/religious grounds, then use what you see to support your ideas.

Comment: @jamesqf: First, I agree that they didn't do science! "Science" as we understand it was not distinguished from many other subjects. The fact they they spoke of "natural history" *demonstrates* how they saw things we'd call scientific as part of a broad subject that included what we'd call history.

Comment: @Mark Olson: Saying that science wasn't distinguished from other subjects betrays a lack of understanding of just what science is.  It's not simply a set of subject areas (like physics, chemistry, and so on) that we call "science", it is a way of looking at the world, which the ancients really didn't have.  See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_method  The ancients would judge an idea on whether it was philosophically satisfying, rather than try to test it by experiment.

Comment: There's different definitions of "science".  I'm currently reading a [book by a theoretical physicist](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/32192022-reality-is-not-what-it-seems) and he repeatedly describes what people like Aristotle, Ptolemy and Democritus were doing as "science".  (And some did indeed experiment, though the "scientific method" was no formulated.)

Comment: @jamessqf,  (the ancients didn't do science).. So **Aristotle** the father of Biology,  you don't believe he actually contributed to Biology. **Democritus** the father of Atomic theory to your mind never pondered atomism?  **Eratosthenes** never pondered astronomy or geography?  **Euclid and Pythagorus**  no impact on Geometry?  **Hipparchus**, Trigonometry?  The ancients may not have had the scientific method, but if science begins with asking a question,  many of those questions were asked first by those ancients.